# There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

[image: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter]

I don't have any idea about this error please how I make that work?

Comment: Can you share CenterExamen.cs? Are you using generics there?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error appears because the base class does not have a default constructor. You need to define a constructor in the derived class, which gets the same parameters as the constructor in the base class, and invokes that base class constructor using the **base** keyword as explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228387(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I could not open the screenshot of CenterExamen class. The error happens becauase your base class CenterExamen does not have a default constructor. It does not mean like you need to have a default constructor in the base class. In such cases, when inheriting a class, the inherited class should instantiate the base class by passing the required parameters.