# How can I pass an instance of LoggerFactory to ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, actionfilterattribute, custom-action-filter

Good day.

I'm trying to use logging by injecting a LoggerFactory in my custom ActionFilterAttribute class but when using the Attribute in one of the controller methods I get an error saying

```
[CS7036] There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'logger' of 'Tracker.Tracker(ILoggerFactory)'
```

Here's the implementation of the class:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace ImmoSales.Tracking
{
    public class Tracker : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public string ActionType { get; set; }
        public string ActionName { get; set; }
        private readonly ILoggerFactory _logger;

        public Tracker(ILoggerFactory logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(context);
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuted(context);
        }

        public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
        {
            base.OnResultExecuting(context);
        }

        public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
        {
            base.OnResultExecuted(context);
        }
    }
}
```

I get the mentioned error when I attempt to use the Tracker in a controller as follows:

```
[Tracker(ActionType="testType", ActionName="testName")]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

What can be done to fix the error?

Comment: Check here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35191476/there-is-no-argument-given-that-corresponds-to-the-required-formal-parameter

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since you are doing constructor injection in your action filter, you may  enable it using `ServiceFilter` attribute where you can pass the type of your filter

```
[ServiceFilter(typeof(Tracker))]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    // to do : return something
}
```

Make sure you have registered the filter in the `ConfigureServices` method

```
services.AddScoped<Tracker>();
```

If you want to pass other arguments to the filter, you can update the filter constructor to have those parameters.

```
public class Tracker : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private string _actionType { get; set; }
    private string _actionName { get; set; }
    private readonly ILoggerFactory _logger;

    public Tracker(ILoggerFactory logger, string actionType, string actionName)
    {
        this._logger = logger;
        this._actionName = actionName;
        this._actionType = actionType;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(context);
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        base.OnResultExecuting(context);
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
    {
        base.OnResultExecuted(context);
    }
}
```

and use `TypeFilter` attribute to enable your filter, where you can explicitly pass the arguments

```
[TypeFilter(typeof(Tracker), Arguments = new object[] { "Abc", "Xyz" })]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    // to do : return something
}
```