# C# LINQ uses the wrong CompareTo

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying something like this:

```
List<MyType> sortedList = one.Concat(two).ToList(); // one and two are both List<MyType>
sortedList.Sort((a, b) => a.Value.CompareTo(b.Value));
```

With `MyType` being like

```
public class MyType
{
    public long Value { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to build this, I get the error:

> error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter '`comparisonType`' of '`MemoryExtensions.CompareTo(ReadOnlySpan<char>, ReadOnlySpan<char>, StringComparison)`'

Looks like it tries to use char's `CompareTo`, instead of long's.

How do I fix this?

Comment: What is the type of the `list` variable? Note that `List.Sort` sorts the list in-place - it does not return a new list. Did you mean `OrderBy`?

Comment: @DStanley now the question more closely resembles my code

Comment: I just ran your code.. it compiles fine. REsult is sorted as well. One thing you cant do is assign .Sort() to a variable as its a void method. list.Sort will in-place sort the list.

Comment: Are you certain that this specific segment of code is causing your issue? The code provided compiles and sorts as expected using longs. Seeing the use of spans leads me to believe that this issue is related to something else besides longs (unless you just simplified your type for the sake of the example).

Any additional context/code would probably be helpful as I don't see any issues with it as is.

Comment: @Jawad I am trying to build on .NET Core with `dotnet build` and `dotnet --version` outputs `2.2.401`

Comment: @RionWilliams the error specifies precisely the line containing `Sort` (the column is the `C` of `CompareTo`), and the error is exactly this error message (I omitted the file names)

Comment: That's very odd and seems like a red herring. Are you doing anything with Spans or any other memory-extension related features of C#? Have you checked this out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35191476/there-is-no-argument-given-that-corresponds-to-the-required-formal-parameter

Comment: @RionWilliams have a look at my answer, I got it to build now by using `OrderBy`. This is indeed odd. I don't know what a Span is, or general memory-extension, but I have not written any of my own extension methods.

Comment: Non-welcoming comment: consider re-reading [MCVE] guidance of posting code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what causes the original error.

Using `OrderBy` instead of `Sort` builds without errors however:

```
List<MyType> sortedList = one.Concat(two).OrderBy(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

So I will use this method.